# Noindex Posts From Certain Authors In Wordpress

Tags: php, functions, author, noindex

I'm trying to noindex posts from all authors EXCEPT 3 authors on my Wordpress site.

I found the following code that I can put into the header.php file. However, this targets specific categories.

```
<?php if (is_single() && (in_category(array(457))))  { 
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">';
} ?>
```

How do I modify this to say something like, if is single post and is NOT an author with ID 111, 112, or 113 then insert noindex, follow. Would the following be correct?:

```
 <?php if (is_single() && !(is_author(array(111,112,113))))  { 
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">';
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From codex: [is_author()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/) is a conditional tag which *determines whether the query is for an existing author archive page.*
so it does not work for your scope.

Best solution, instead of using the template file *header.php* is to write a function in *functions.php* hooking the proper action `wp_head`:

```
add_action('wp_head','AS_exclude_author_from_indexing');

function AS_exclude_author_from_indexing(){
  $toIndex = array(111,112,113);
  $user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
  if( !in_array($user_id,$toIndex)){
    echo "<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex,follow\">".PHP_EOL;
  } 
}
```